# Iterando paginas web usando Requests e Python

Tags: python-3.x, http-request, web-scraping, python-requests

Sou iniciante em web scraping. Como aprendizado to fazendo um banco de dados a partir de dados sobre venda de carros seminovos em alguns sites. Um dos sites eh esse

```
url = https://www.seminovosunidas.com.br/veiculos/page:1?utm_source=afilio&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=maio&utm_content=ron_ambos&utm_term=120x600_promocaomaio_performance_-_-%22
```

Consigo pegar os dados que preciso da pagina normalmente. Para iterar uso um url.format passando como argumento um indice que vai incrementando a pagina.

O codigo completo:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_unidas():
    url = "https://www.seminovosunidas.com.br/veiculos/page:{}?utm_source=afilio&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=maio&utm_content=ron_ambos&utm_term=120x600_promocaomaio_performance_-_-"
    indice_pagina = 1
    dados = {}
    while True:
        #headers = {'User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list)}
        r = req.get(url.format(indice_pagina))
        if r.status_code != req.codes.ok:
            raise Exception("Página inexistente") 
        soup = bs(r.text, "lxml")
        carros = soup.find_all(class_="vehicleDescription")
        valores = soup.find_all(class_="valor")
        for carro, valor in zip(carros,valores):
            texto = list(carro.stripped_strings)
            dados["Empresa"] = "Unidas"
            dados["Modelo"] = texto[2]
            dados["Preco"] = valor.text.replace(".","").replace(",",".")
            dados["Kilometragem"] = texto[4].split(",")[1][5:]
            dados["Ano"] = texto[3][-5:-1]
            #print(dados)
            #print("#######################################")        

get_unidas()
```

O problema eh sei que nao como fazer para o while acabar. 
Ao acessar uma pagina com indice inexistente, indice 200 por exemplo, ele volta pra pagina 1.
Normalmente uma pagina nao existente tem o HTML diferente, logo consigo diferenciar de uma pagina que existe. 
Mesmo checando o status_code ao acessar uma pagina nao existente eh retornado 200, o codigo que indica pagina existente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você está em uma página, é setado o valor `active` no atributo da tag `li` da paginação:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline header-paginator pull-right">
  <li class="active number"><a>1</a></li>
  <li class="number"><a href="/veiculos/page:2?utm_source=afilio&amp;utm_medium=display&amp;utm_campaign=maio&amp;utm_content=ron_ambos&amp;utm_term=120x600_promocaomaio_performance_-_-%22">2</a></li>
  <li class="number"><a href="/veiculos/page:3?utm_source=afilio&amp;utm_medium=display&amp;utm_campaign=maio&amp;utm_content=ron_ambos&amp;utm_term=120x600_promocaomaio_performance_-_-%22">3</a></li>
  <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
  <li class="number"><a href="/veiculos/page:106?utm_source=afilio&amp;utm_medium=display&amp;utm_campaign=maio&amp;utm_content=ron_ambos&amp;utm_term=120x600_promocaomaio_performance_-_-%22">106</a></li>
</ul>
```

Então, em vez de verificar o `status_code`, você pode busca o elemento `li.active.number` e verificar o texto, se o indice atual for maior ou igual a 2 e o valor do elemento for igual a 1, você finaliza o loop.

Remova as linhas:

```
if r.status_code != req.codes.ok:
  raise Exception("Página inexistente")
```

e abaixo da linha:

```
soup = bs(r.text, "lxml")
```

coloque:

```
pagina_atual = list(soup.find(class_="active number").stripped_strings)[0]
if indice_pagina >= 2 and pagina_atual == '1': break
```

também não esqueça de fazer o incremento em `indice_pagina`, caso contrário irá ficar em loop infinito, após `for` coloque:

```
indice_pagina += 1
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/WarpedDistantObjectdatabase)

Comment: Muito obrigado, cara. Funcionou direitinho